# Best book for first order predicate logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am having problem understanding first order predicate logic, rules of inferences, proof by natural deduction. From which I should read them for better understanding. Also if there any websites or lectures that are useful in this.
Thanks

Comment: For a list of books, see : [Teach Yourself Logic: A Study Guide](http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/).

Answer (score 1):

As an introduction, I like [Mathematical Logic : A course with exercises -- Part I -- Propositional Calculus, Boolean Algebras, Predicate Calculus, Completeness Theorems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198500483). Translation of a French book.